# how to add a linear percent indicator

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to create a linear percent indicator that i can show its percent in text widget 
like this

[image]

i found a library like that which its name was `percent_indicator`
but it does not have what i am trying to implement 
is there any packages that does look more like that?

Comment: What is the specific part that you tried to implement but the package doesn't have any support? And please add some code you have.

Comment: i want to create a percent indicator that i can show its percent in text widget

Answer (score 1):

Use Flutter's [LinearProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) as the main part although if you want that special background than you would likely need to create a custom widget. The image can be achieved by using a [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html). The top of the column would have a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html). Then, use the [text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget in the row and the align widget to [align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) it to the right, left and centre.

Or instead of using flutter's LinearProgressIndicator, create a custom [stateful](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) widget with a [stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and as it's child a blue [container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) that resizes over a grey container that doesn't resize.

Use BoxShadow to create shadows.

Comment: thanks , so how to change the text according to its percent

Comment: When the percent is updated use `setState`. What you should be creating is a stateful widget. Learn about stateful widgets. You can change floats into text by using `.toString`

Comment: thanks for your help i vote your answer up

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer if it works for you. This way people know this question is solved.